# Why use the javascript function wrapper (added in coffeescript) ".call(this)"

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

When I use the latest (1.0) release of coffee-script, a simple javascript output looks like this (by default):

```
(function() {
  var a;
  a = 1;
}).call(this);
```

What does **.call(this)** do and what would be the reason to add it?

Comment: can you also show us the code that yields this js?

Comment: My guess is that it's the simplest way to make all variables have local function (not global) scope by default and to give access to parent scope through 'this'

Comment: This is an excellent article on the subject of namespacing your JS: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/namespacing-in-javascript/

Comment: @Gabi Purcaru: This would be generated by the CoffeeScript `a = 1`.

Comment: If you wonder why `.call(this)` was used instead of the normal IIFE call, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21736430/1048572) on "Why write “.call(this)” at the end of an javascript anonyms function?"

Comment: See also the good answers at [Pattern for CoffeeScript modules](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5211638/1048572)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's creating a function and then calling itself with the parent function/objects scope.

.call and .apply are different methods of invoking a function. You basically created a function that does nothing except set a=1 within its own scope.

In javascript you need to realize that every function is a object, and `this` is what refers to the current object/function. Using `.call(this)` overrides `this` from within the function and replaces it with the one from the calling context.

Answer (score 34):

It's a way to make sure that the compiled CoffeeScript has its own scope for variable names. This has benefits in terms of efficiency and simplicity (you know you the generated JavaScript won't stomp on variables used by other code). You can disable it with the `--bare` (or `-b`) option to the CoffeeScript compiler.

The reason for the `call(this)` is just to ensure that the CoffeeScript has the same `this` as the scope where it's placed, because functions don't normally inherit their `this` object from the surrounding context.

Comment: How is this different than a self exec funct? Like: 

(function() {
  /* Code */
})();

Comment: The self-executing function loses it's notion of `this`, when it doesn't happen to be loaded in a browser context. Some CommonJS platforms evaluate loaded files with a specific `this`.

Comment: I fully understand the variable scope reasons, but I'm curious to know how there's an efficiency benefit. Are you referring to efficiency of the compiler, or of the generated JavaScript?