# jQuery bind events with Rails/Coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

So in `app/assets/javascript/faye.js.coffee.erb` I have the following:

```
$('#room_tag').bind('blur', () ->
   alert('Hey!')
)
```

All the other code in it such as: `sendmessage('room', 'message')` work just fine. And I can copy and paste the code generated from the block above and paste it into Chrome it works fine. I assume this is because, is it rails or coffeescript?, either way one of them, wraps the entire file in:

```
(function() {
  // your generated code here
}).call(this);
```

Also would there happen to be a way for me to access methods that are defined within there? Is it possible to define a method in there without assigning it to a variable?

Comment: I don't know, I just saw this and... wanted some coffee...

Comment: The second part of this question is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211638/pattern-for-coffeescript-modules/ See my answer there, explaining the wrapper's purpose. (Though in this case, the wrapper isn't causing the issue, as Peter says in his answer.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1) Most likely your `.bind` call is executing too soon, before the document is ready and thus it doesn't do anything.  Wrap it in a call to `$(document).ready` like this

```
    $(document).ready ->
      $('#room_tag').bind 'blur', ->
        alert 'Hey!'
```

And there's actually a cute shortcut for this since jQuery's default `$` function is an alias for `$(document).ready`, you can just do:

```
$ ->
  $('#room_tag').bind 'blur', ->
    alert 'Hey!'
```

2) It is coffeescript that wraps everything in a self-executing function definition.

3) If you want to make a global function in coffeescript, explicitly assign it as a property of the global window object

```
    window.myFunc = (arg1) ->
      alert arg1
```

2) & 3) are clearly explained in the [CoffeeScript docs](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/)

Comment: From the Coffee Docs `The usual caveats about CoffeeScript apply — your inline scripts will run within a closure wrapper, so if you want to expose global variables or functions, attach them to the window object.`

Comment: Exactly, sounds like #1 is the answer here. You can confirm this by checking `$('#room_tag').length`. If it's `1`, the element exists at the time of the selection; if it's `0`, it doesn't.