# ReferenceError: CoffeeScript + JsTestDriver + Qunit

Tags: javascript, tdd, coffeescript, qunit, js-test-driver

Currently I'm looking into TDD with CoffeeScript and JsTestDriver however I'm stuck on a ReferenceError thrown by JsTestDriver.

**Some info:**

- Using the IntelliJ JsTestDriver plugin
- Testing via Chrome
- Configured JsTestDriver the same way as on: http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/wiki/QUnitAdapter
- Writing the tests in CoffeeScript
- CoffeeScript is compiled to javascript and put in the configured directories before the test is run

**Config**

```
server: http://Mark-PC:9876/capture

load:
  - js/lib/main/*.js
  - js/lib/test/sinon.js
  - js/lib/test/qunit.js
  - js/lib/test/equiv.js
  - js/lib/test/QUnitAdapter.js
  - js/coffee/main/controllers/*.js
  - js/coffee/main/models/*.js
  - js/coffee/test/controllers/*.js
```

**Controller**

```
class PortfolioController extends Backbone.Controller
    constructor: ->

    test: (a, b) ->
        return a + b
```

**Test code**

```
module("PortfolioController", {
    setup: -> @routeSpy = sinon.spy()
    teardown: -> window.location.hash = ""
})

test 'indexRoute', ->
    c = new PortfolioController
    equals c.test(1, 1), 2, "1 + 1 = 2"
```

**Problem**

JsTestDriver throws a error

```
ReferenceError: PortfolioController is not defined
ReferenceError: PortfolioController is not defined
    at Object. (http://mark-pc:9876/test/js/coffee/test/controllers/PortfolioController.test.js:12:5)
    at [object Object].test indexRoute (http://mark-pc:9876/test/js/lib/test/QUnitAdapter.js:40:15)
```

**Tried:**

- Removing dependancies such as jQuery, BackBone, etc
- Removed Qunit adapter and tried with jstestdriver asserts
- **Added a class inside the test itself, then it worked**

Seems like some kinda exporting issue or prototype conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to make `PortfolioController` a global, perhaps by adding

```
root = window ? global
root.PortfolioController = PortfolioController
```

the end of the file, or by simply replacing

```
class PortfolioController extends Backbone.Controller
```

with

```
class @PortfolioController extends Backbone.Controller
```

taking advantage of the fact that `this` is the global root in that context.

CoffeeScript never exports anything beyond a file's scope automatically; you have to do it explicitly. See my explanation for this behavior [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211638/pattern-for-coffeescript-modules/5212449#5212449).