# Set up a coffee script unit test in JsTestDriver

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, coffeescript

I am trying to implement a very basic unit test for **CoffeeScript**/JavaScript with **JsTestDriver**. I've got two files:

1.) *lib/Greeter.coffee*

```
greet = (name) ->
    "Hello #{name}"
```

2.) lib/GreeterTest.coffee

```
tests = {
    "Test 1": -> assertEquals("Hello World!", greet "World")
}

TestCase("Test for introducing the test framework", tests)
```

My *jsTestDriver.conf* defines their path with the line: `- lib/*.js` When executing the test, however, I get: `Total 0 tests (Passed 0; Fails: 0; Errors: 0)`

I am sure, that the test can be located, because inserting an obvious program error leads to the detection that error in the concrete file. Also inserting an alert invocation leads to the expected behavior: In the browser being captured I see the alert-Message Box

Am I missing something? How could something like this be debugged?

---

What does work though is the following:

```
TestCase("Test case 1", {

    testGreet: ->
        greeter = new Greeter
        assertEquals("Hello World!", greeter.greet "World")
})
```

and

```
class @Greeter

   constructor: ->

   greet: (name) ->
        return "Hello #{name}!"
```

If both files reside in the same folder, you can drop the `@`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this question: [ReferenceError: CoffeeScript + JsTestDriver + Qunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244623/referenceerror-coffeescript-jstestdriver-qunit). You've got the same issue, in that `greet =` defines a local variable that isn't visible outside of `Greeter.coffee`. Change it to `window.greet =` or `@greet =`.

However, that doesn't explain the `Total 0 tests` issue. I'm not intimately familiar with JsTestDriver, but on [this page](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/wiki/TestCase) it's suggested that test names have to start with "test"—could it be that the capitalized name `"Test 1"` is ignored? Try changing it to `"test1"`.

Comment: You might be right, I added to my question a possible solution. There the test function starts with "test"

Comment: So if `testGreet:` works but `TestGreet:` doesn't, you should mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Don't rush, there is an ongoing discussion about the time gap between reading an answer and accepting it on stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when you run `java -jar $JSTESTDRIVER -tests all` you are in the some directory as your test, this should take care of the "total 0 test" issue. I had the same problem.

Comment: No, it was actually caused that I didn't named the test functions with prefix "test..", but +1 for telling another possible reason!