# QUnit + coffeescript scope

Tags: coffeescript, qunit

In Javascript polluting the global namespace is generally regarded as a bad thing. This is why Coffeescript wraps all of your Javascript in a `(function() {}).call(this);` wrapper.

However, I've begun writing QUnit tests for my Coffeescript code, and QUnit complains that it can't find my functions.

```
1. Died on test #1: getGoodNamePart is not defined
getGoodNamePart is not defined at Object.<anonymous> (file:///Users/kevin/Documents/docs/code/chrome/tests.js:2:10) at Object.run
```

I'd like to test the variables without polluting the global namespace. What's a good way to do this?

Here's the generated Javascript I want to test:

```
(function() {
getGoodNamePart = function(str) {
    if (str.charAt(0) === '"') {
      str.replace(/" <[^>]+>$"/g, "");
      str.replace(/"/g, "");
      return str;
    } else if (str.charAt(0) === '<') {
      str.replace(/<|>/g, "");
      return str;
    } else {
      return str;
    }
  };
}).call(this);
```

and my test.js file is:

```
test('getGoodNamePart()', function() {
  equals(getGoodNamePart("\"Kev Burke\" <kev@inburke.com>"), "Kev Burke", "\"name\" <email> works");
  equals(getGoodNamePart("", "", "empty string works"));
  equals(getGoodNamePart("kev@inburke.com", "kev@inburke.com", "raw email works"));
  return equals(getGoodNamePart("<kev@inburke.com>", "kev@inburke.com", "email inside carets -> carets get stripped"));
});
```

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Some example code would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I added an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, you say you want to test `getGoodNamePart` without polluting the global namespace. But, CoffeeScript automatically modularizes each file (with good reason—see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211638/pattern-for-coffeescript-modules/5212449#5212449)), which means that the only way to access functions across files is to attach them to some global object. (I'm assuming that we're talking about the browser here, not a CommonJS environment, such as Node.js, where you'd use `exports`.)

That gives you three options:

1. Attach `getGoodNamePart` to `window`. This is easiest, since the only change needed is prefixing `getGoodNamePart` with `window.` (or just `@`), but of course this maximizes namespace pollution.
2. Attach `getGoodNamePart` to something else that's already attached to `window` or `global`.
3. Move your tests inside of the same file as `getGoodNamePart` (an unusual practice in the JS world, but one worth considering, as it keeps the global namespace untouched and lets you easily go between your code and your tests).

Let's say that you want to go with #2, exporting functions like `getGoodNamePart` purely for testing. Call them "test targets." At the top of each file with a test target, add

```
window.testTargets ?= {}
```

and when you define `getGoodNamePart`, write

```
testTargets.getGoodNamePart = getGoodNamePart = (str) ->
  ...
```

Then at the top of your QUnit test suite, write

```
{getGoodNamePart} = testTargets
```

to get the function.

Answer (score 2):

I compile the coffee file with the --bare flag, for testing purpose
`$ coffee -c -b your_file`

this doesn't modularize compiled code