# Declaring backbone extension class in another file - coffeescript

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I have the following class that extends Backbone.View, I want all my backbone views to inherit from this class:

```
class BaseView
  constructor: (options) ->
    @bindings = []
    Backbone.View.apply(@, [options])

  _.extend(BaseView.prototype, Backbone.View.prototype, {
  #etc. tec.

BaseView.extend = Backbone.View.extend
```

I can then extend my own view like this:

```
class BusinessUnitsView extends BaseView
  initialize: (options) ->
```

This all works fine if they are in the same file but if I separate BaseView into a different file, I get an error message:

> BaseView is undefined

How can I keep the BaseView in a different file and use it to extend my custom views?

Comment: CoffeeSript's auto-scoping is a very common source of confusion along these lines. This question, and the answers on it, should clarify matters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211638/pattern-for-coffeescript-modules/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this under `BaseView.extend = Backbone.View.extend`

```
@.BaseView = BaseView
```

it makes your BaseView global accessible

I always declare my classes like this and it works great

```
class BaseView extends Backbone.View

@.BaseView = BaseView
```

Comment: So it works now right? Or you need a better answer? I updated my answer the way I always declare my backbone classes. Hope it works!