# Include Coffescript generated javascript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have the following Coffeescript in test.js

```
yo () -> console.log("yo")
```

When compiled via coffee -o public/javascripts/ -cw public/coffeescripts/, I get public/javascripts/test.js:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.4.0
(function() {
  var yo;

  yo = function() {
    return console.log('yo');
  };

}).call(this);
```

I'm trying to include this in the usual way in an HTML file:

```
<script src="/javascripts/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
  $(function() {
    alert('before yo');
    yo();
    alert('after yo');
  });
  //]]>
</script>
```

However I keep getting "Uncaught Reference Error: yo is not defined".  Whats the process for actually using the javascript generated by Coffeescript?

Comment: What's your question? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CoffeeScript & Global Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables)

Comment: `@yo () -> console.log("yo")` appears to be the solution.

Comment: You forgot to export the `yo` symbol.

Comment: @Shmiddty i'm not sure it's a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CoffeeScript file, `yo` is a local variable. It is not a global variable. If you want to use that variable from another JavaScript file or from JavaScript in the HTML file, then you will need to make `yo` a global variable.

You can do this in the CoffeeScript file like so:

```
yo = -> ...

# either
@yo = yo
# or
window.yo = yo
```

Answer (score 2):

The generated Javascript from your Coffeescript needs a tweak to export `yo` outside the calling context.

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.4.0
(function(context) { // changed this line (note: context == 'this' which is being passed in at last line)
  var yo;

  yo = function() {
     return console.log('yo');
  };

  context.yo = yo; //export yo to the context.

}).call(this);
```

Commonly, instead of `this`, will you see people pass in `window` and/or `document` when the code is used in the context of a web page (as opposed to server-side Node.js calling context).

I updated the Javascript, but you can have easily used the 'module export' idiom which you can read more about here -  [Pattern for CoffeeScript modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211638/pattern-for-coffeescript-modules)

Comment: @yo solution prevented me from tweaking the javascript, but your solution gave me some more background on the underlying issue of the coffeescript module pattern...so I upvoted as well.

Comment: Updating the CoffeeScript and recompiling it is generally preferable to letting the generated file go out of sync with the original source.