# Top-level variables aren't globally-scoped and return values are mandatory in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

```
funName = () ->
  $(".foo").addClass("bar");
```

Compiles into the scope of an anonymous function. Calling `funName` from the console results in `undefined`.

```
(function() {
  var funName;
  funName = function() {
    return $(".foo").addClass("bar");
  };
}).call(this);
```

What's its reasoning for compiling like this and how do I work with it?

Also any insight on the mandatory return within functions using CoffeeScript would be great. Why is it like that? How do I need to code differently because of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mike has answered the main question here. The modular wrapper a common point of confusion for CoffeeScript newcomers, as illustrated by these related questions:

- [How do I define global variables in CoffeeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables)
- [Why use the javascript function wrapper (added in coffeescript) ".call(this)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542942/why-use-the-javascript-function-wrapper-added-in-coffeescript-callthis)
- [Getting rid of CoffeeScript's closure wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693211/getting-rid-of-coffeescripts-closure-wrapper)

As to your other question: If you don't want a function to return anything, simply make the last line of that function either `return` by itself or, equivalently, `undefined`. Either will compile to a function with no `return`. For instance:

```
funName = ->
  $(".foo").addClass "bar"
  return
```

compiles to

```
var funName;
funName = function() {
  $(".foo").addClass("bar");
};
```

Note that there is an ongoing discussion ([issue 899](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/899)) about a possible alternative syntax for defining no-return functions. If the current proposal were accepted, you'd be able to write your function as

```
funName = -/> $(".foo").addClass "bar"
```

If you like that syntax, you should voice your support for it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a global `funName` try using `root = exports ? this` and then `root.funName = ...` as described at [How do I define global variables in CoffeeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables)

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be an older thread, but I've encountered the same problem and noticed an interesting command you can add into the compiler enviroment to fix this problem.

The command **-b** or **--bare** is used to compile the JavaScript **without** the top-level function safety wrapper. After I added that command when I compiled my CoffeeScript file, it removed that odd wrapper:

```
(function() {
    var funName;
    funName = function() {
       return $(".foo").addClass("bar");
    };
 }).call(this);
```

I use WebStorm as my IDE enviroment and this is my compiler statement I use:

```
--compile --bare $FileName$
```