# CoffeeScript function created in app/assets/javascript not found

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

In my CoffeeScript file, `clients.js.coffee`,

```
myFunction = (variable) ->
```

I created a function in CoffeeScript in `app/assets/javascript`. But when I try to call that function, the console shows me an error saying function not found.

I check the source of the page and it shows that the script is loaded:

```
<script src="/assets/clients.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is what was found inside the script source:

```
(function() {
  var myFunction;

  myFunction = function(variable) {}
}).call(this);
```

Any idea what am I missing? What should I do to call the function?

Comment: You have created a function in an anonymous function scope. So it's not visible outside

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is this happening to my CoffeeScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481986/why-is-this-happening-to-my-coffeescript)

Comment: How do I solve it in rails? Thanks

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To make it accessible from outside, all you need to do is add an '@' in front.
This will attach the function to the window object.

```
@myFunction = (variable) ->
```

Answer (score 7):

Bind it to the window

```
myFunction = (variable) ->
  alert('zzzzzzzz')

window.myFunction = myFunction
```

Comment: Also here is a screencast which might be helpful - http://house9.blogspot.com/2011/05/rails-31-javascript-execution.html