# Wrapping Libraries | jQuery vs. Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Here is the [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js) wrapper

```
(function(){
    // Backbone.js
}).call(this);
```

For comparison.  Here is the [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) wrapper:

```
(function( window, undefined ) {
    // jQuery.js
})( window );
```

**Regarding the BackBone Wrapper:**

I understand the need for a immediately invoked (via call) function expression - to provide privacy (encapsulation)

I understand why it is an anonymous function - to reduce global symbols.

However I don't understand what 'this' refers to?  + Why the difference in wrappers?

**Reference**

[MDN - this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: The same thing it always does .. in the global scope it is a synonym for `window`. Using `call` then makes sure the `this` inside the function evaluates to the same object as the `this` outside ..

Comment: The "jQuery way" is generally `function ($) { .. }(jQuery)` to avoid `$` clashes, afaik. Perhaps it is preference or perhaps the code wasn't/isn't (always) in the same (global) context?

Comment: I don't understand what I am looking for in there :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why write ".call(this)" at the end of an javascript anonyms function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035822/why-write-callthis-at-the-end-of-an-javascript-anonyms-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It helps preserving the value of `this` in the inner function.

A call to an unbound function* resets `this` to the global object, i.e `window` in case of a browser.

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/scE6R/):

```
(function () {
    alert("1: " + this); // this == myObject

    (function () {
        alert("2: " + this); // this == window
    })();

    (function () {
        alert("3: " + this); // this == myObject
    }).call(this);
}).call(myObject);
```

*) I.e. calling `func()` instead of `obj.func()`. `this` would become `obj` in the latter case.

---

First clarification:

In case of backbone.js the reason why they wrap their code in `(function () {...}).call(this)` is that this way you don't need to know the actual name of the global object (`global` in case of node.js).

See http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-4

---

Second clarification:

If the script is run by a browser, `this` is the same object as `window` if you are not in the call context of a bound function. In a standalone JS engine (node, rhino …) the global object is not named `window` but `global`.

The jQuery developers know you want to run their script in a browser, because you would have little fun with it if you don't have a document to manipulate in first place.

Backbone.js, like [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org), is general purpose so the developers do not know the name of the global object. And they don't care.

So when jQuery does

```
(function (window) {
    ...
})(window);
```

it could have been implemented this way too

```
(function () {
    var window = this;
    ...
}).call(window);
```

and because `this===window`

```
(function () {
    var window = this;
    ...
}).call(this);
```

Read the examples backwards to see what the backbone hackers did. (They call the global object `root`. You may want to read the annotated code.)

I for one would have chosen

```
(function (root) {
    ...
})(this);
```

but in the end it does not matter I guess.