# Javascript function implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code like this :

```
(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //event handlers
    $('.project-delete').on('click', function() {
        deleteProject($(this));
    });

    $('.keyword-delete').on('click', function() {
        deleteKeyword($(this));
  });
  this.deleteKeyword = function(model) {
    }
}).call(this);
```

I am curious if this is a good approach since I was learning JS recently and as far as I understand this function will have global scope, doesn't it ? since `.call(this)` is passing window object to this closure then I think it is not the best option ? Is there something I am missing ? Does changing `.call(this)` to just `()` change anything ?

EDIT:So is it OK to just pass window object to that closure ? Wouldn't it better to pass just a empty object or jQuery object ?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035822/why-write-callthis-at-the-end-of-an-javascript-anonyms-function

Comment: It will explicitly bind the closure's context to the parent's context. Same as `(function(){ }).apply(this)`

Comment: Note that I would define "scope" as being about what variables the function has access to (i.e., its own local variables plus those of any functions that it is nested inside), and that has nothing to do with the value of `this`.

Comment: @nnnnnn so isn't it a better option to apply jQuery object (or maybe just empty object) to it to increase performance ? Wouldn't it increase performance if this would point to local scope ? Since window object is very slow. It is not like I need a performance here, but I am just curious if it is a good way to call this function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this function is defined in the global scope, the `deleteKeyword` function will have also have global scope since `this` in the context of the parent function is basically `window` (which has been passed in as `this` from outside; in the global scope `this === window`).

If you change `.call(this)` to just `()`, `this` is still `window` inside the function. This is because when you call a function via a simple function-call, `this` is set to the global object, which is `window`.

If you want a different value for `this`, you will need to pass in something else via `.call` or `.apply`.

For more information about the behavior of `this`, take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 1):

> *"as far as I understand this function will have global scope, doesn't it?"*

"Scope" is about what variables a function has access to (i.e., its own local variables, plus locals declared in any functions that it might be nested inside, plus global variables), and that has nothing to do with the value of `this`. Scope depends on where the function declaration is, but `this` depends on how the function is called.

> *"since* `.call(this)` *is passing* `window` *object to this closure"*

We can't tell that just from the code shown. Presumably you mean that that block of code is not nested inside some other function, so then yes, `this` would be `window`. But if that code was ever pasted inside some other function then that `this` might have some other value depending on how that other function was called.

> *"Does changing* `.call(this)` *to just* `()` *change anything?"*

If you use just `()` that will mean that inside the function `this` will be `window`. Whether that changes anything depends on whether the `this` in `.call(this)` was `window` in the first place - as I already mentioned above, if that block were nested inside some other function `this` could be something else. Having said that, for the code shown **if `this` was anything other than `window` I think your code would break.** Because you declare a function like this:

```
this.deleteKeyword = function(model) {...}
```

...and then inside the second click handler you call what I assume is meant to be the same function *without* using `this`:

```
deleteKeyword($(this));
```

The only way that will work is if `this` is `window` and the `deleteKeyword()` function is thus global. If `this` were any other object the function would be a property of that other object and thus not accessible directly as `deleteKeyword()`. But unless you specifically want `deleteKeyword()` to be accessible from other code not shown there is no reason to create it as a property of `this` at all. Just declare it with `var`:

```
var deleteKeyword = function(...
```

...and then it will be accessible only inside that function and the ones nested in it such as your click handler. And the `.call()` at the end of your function would be redundant since the function wouldn't ever actually use `this`.

> *"so isn't it a better option to apply jQuery object (or maybe just empty object) to it to increase performance? Wouldn't it increase performance if this would point to local scope? Since window object is very slow."*

Well as I already said, "scope" and the value of `this` are unrelated concepts. I'm not sure why you are worrying about performance for that code. But if you were to apply jQuery or an empty object with `.call(jQuery)` or `.call({})` the code would not work as explained above.

Comment: I am just more like curious about that. I just want to make use of good practices. Would it be better if i declare var that = {} an change everywhere 'this' for 'that' (also attach that in handlers)? Is it cleaner solution ? I am sorry if these questions sounds stupid, but it is pretty interesting for me.

Comment: `var that = {}` sounds like you're just over-complicating it. Take a step back: why do you think you need to use `this` within that function at all?