# Can't Call a Function

Tags: javascript, html, image

**JFiddler** - http://jsfiddle.net/x2Uwg/

So I have a fade function which first fades the image in and then fades it out. I'd like the image to fade in, change and then fade out. The problem is the only way I can get the img to fade out is if I have it in a button like this.

```
<button class="hide2" onclick="fadeEffect.init('chestImg', 0)">Fade Out</div>
```

I'd like for it to be something like this

> Img is show
>
> User clicks one button
>
> Image fades in, then changes.
>
> Image fades out.

Right now it is like this.

> Img is show
>
> User clicks one button
>
> Image fades in, then changes.
>
> User clicks another button
>
> Image fades out.

My fade function looks like so.

```
var fadeEffect=function(){
return{
    init:function(id, flag, target){
        this.elem = document.getElementById(id);
        clearInterval(this.elem.si);
        this.target = target ? target : flag ? 100 : 0;
        this.flag = flag || -1;
        this.alpha = this.elem.style.opacity ? parseFloat(this.elem.style.opacity) * 100 : 0;
        this.elem.si = setInterval(function(){fadeEffect.tween()}, 20);
    },
    tween:function(){
        if(this.alpha == this.target){
            clearInterval(this.elem.si);
        }else{
            var value = Math.round(this.alpha + ((this.target - this.alpha) * .05)) + (1 * this.flag);
            this.elem.style.opacity = value / 100;
            this.elem.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value + ')';
            this.alpha = value
        }
    }
}
}();
```

I call the fade in like so

```
fadeEffect.init('chestImg', 1);
```

And the fade out like so

```
fadeEffect.init('chestImg', 0);
```

But if I place them in the same function it will not work. Any help?

Comment: jsfiddle link would help us to help u

Comment: @fscore http://jsfiddle.net/x2Uwg/ How do I add the images?

Comment: Upload your image to some image uploading service for example postimage. After u did that, copy paste the url in your jsfiddle and it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call both `fadeEffect.init('chestImg', 1);` and `fadeEffect.init('chestImg', 0);` in the same function, then both effects are running simultaneously, which I think is leading to your problem. I think that what you need to do is:

```
fadeEffect.init('chestImg', 1);
setTimeout(function(){fadeEffect.init('chestImg', 0);},20);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is with binding `this`. When a function is called from within the clickhandler of a button, `this` is set to that button node. You can manually set the `this` object by using the `call` function

```
var button = document.getElementById('hide-id');

fadeEffect.init.call(button,'chestImg', 0);
```

[Why write ".call(this)" at the end of an javascript anonymous function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035822/why-write-callthis-at-the-end-of-an-javascript-anonyms-function)