# IIFE invocation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Two methods I've seen (I know there are more) of using an IIFE:

```
(function(){
    console.log(this);
}).call(this);

(function(){
    console.log(this);
})();
```

Is there any reason to use `.call(this)` on the first one? Won't `();` yield the same context within the function?

Comment: related: [Why use the javascript function wrapper “.call(this)”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4542942/1048572)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on where the code is executed.

`.call(this)` explicitly sets the `this` to the object you pass to `.call`. Only using `();` will set `this` to `window` (or to `undefined` in strict mode).

If the code is executed in global scope it will be the same. If not, then you will get different results if `this` does not refer to `window` (or is `undefined`).

Example:

```
var obj = {
   foo: function() {
       (function(){
           console.log(this); // this === obj
       }).call(this); // this === obj

       (function(){
           console.log(this); // this === window
       })();
   }
};

obj.foo();
```

[**More information about `this` on MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Felix as i know IIFE always refers to window object in non strict mode, and undefined in strict mode, so...

Comment: An IIFE is a normal function. You can set `this` explicitly with `.call` or `.apply`.