# javascript global / local variables and return variable to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry if i am not clear enough as i am new to javascript.

let me explain with an example.

for example if i have

*

```
(function()
var foo;
windows.foo = foo = (function()){
function foo (a,b){
this.colour = a.colour
this.shape = b.shape
}
return foo;
})();
}).call(this);*
```

Now my questions was

1. regarding the scope, when the "foo" is global and local.

2.how would I display the value of foo in the HTML. I cannot use document.getElementbyid(); is there any other functions that i can use?????

Comment: It should be `getElementById`, not `getelementbyid`.

Comment: `here the second asdf is a class and the fist asdf is a global variable.` wrong, on both points. `// why Parenthesis "()";` research IIFE. `// what does it mean and its significance?` depends on what `this` is and what it is executing (you left that out). Question two just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937022/iife-invocation-in-javascript. Notice that the inner IIFE is totally pointless.

Comment: PUT ON HOLD untill when....You stupidd dumbbb mother fcÄkers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By

```
var asdf;
```

you declare a variable in the current scope.

```
window.asdf = ...
```

sets the value of the property "asdf" of the object named "window".

The

```
return asdf;
```

returns the function "asdf" just declared; this is assigned to your (local) variable "asdf" as well as to window.asdf.
The parenthesis call the locally defined function (resulting in the before-mentioned return).

```
.call(obj);
```

invokes the function and sets the this-pointer inside the function to "obj".