# Self-executing anonymous function conventions

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between the following? Do they all work in the same way?

I've seen certain use-cases for `.call()` but I've never seen an explanation as to why the function call brackets are either inside or after the anonymous function declaration.

```
(function() {

}());
 ^^
```

```
(function() {

})();
  ^^
```

```
(function() {

}).call();
```

Comment: SO's search needs to up it's game, as I couldn't find the duplicate.

Comment: Well, that question doesn't ask about `call`, which is why I reversed myself when I closed this as a duplicate originally (and now can't reverse Bergi's having done so).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Hm, this question seems to be mainly interested in "*why the function call brackets are either inside or after*". Admittedly, multiple questions in one post are never good :-) Ben, if you want to know about `.call`, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937022/iife-invocation-in-javascript, I've never seen `.call()` without arguments though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location of the `()` inside or outside the main `()` doesn't matter in the slightest. (Much) more discussion [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions), but that question doesn't address the `call` option you raised.

`call` requires at least one argument [according to the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4), so to be largely the same as your first two options, you'd want:

```
(function() {
}).call(undefined);
```

...to be sure some implementation doesn't get uppity with you for not supplying the argument.

Comment: So, we meet again, TJ Crowder...

Comment: I don't see how `call` requires any arguments? `.call()` is just equivalent to `.call(undefined)` as always.

Comment: @Bergi: No, the spec doesn't say it's optional. There's a difference between calling `foo()` and `foo(undefined)` -- in the former, we're calling without any arguments (`arguments.length` is 0); in the latter, we're calling with `undefined` as an argument (`arguments.length` is 1). As the spec doesn't list `thisArg` as optional, I wouldn't leave it off, even if most implementations wouldn't care (which may or may not be true, I've never tested it).

Comment: Was just about to ask, why doesn't it throw an error when omitting arguments to `call`.

Comment: @BenFortune: Tolerant implementation. :-) Say you have `function foo(arg)`: In **JavaScript**, you'd have to go out of you way in your `foo` code to tell the difference between being called via `foo()` or `foo(undefined)`, because `arg` would have the value `undefined` either way. (You'd have to check `arguments.length`) But the underlying implementation of `Function#call` isn't likely to be in JavaScript, so relying on that would be a bad idea.

Comment: Of course `arguments.length` is different, I meant that the one formal (non-optional) parameter is filled up with `undefined` as described in http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5 - `.call()` is a plain function call after all. I'm pretty sure that it's forbidden to throw exceptions that are not explicitly described in the spec.

Answer (score 3):

The first two are the same, and differ by style only*; the last one is different in that it gives you the ability to control what the value of `this` will be inside the IIFE.  For example

```
(function(){
    this.a = 12;
}).call(foo);
```

will add the property `a` to the object foo.

---

*Of course Douglas Crockford [has a preference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGArABpLy0k)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer 2nd way. JSLint uses the first way. You should always use `.call()` with an argument, so the third variant is wrong.

There is no difference between 1 and 2 though.