# Converting threejs' IIFE functions to es6?

Tags: javascript, three.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to break my threejs project into smaller modules and I'm having a tough time. Take this function for example:

```
var updateCamera = (function() {
    var euler = new THREE.Euler( 0, 0, 0, 'YXZ' );

    return function() {
        euler.x = motion.rotation.x;
        euler.y = motion.rotation.y;
        camera.quaternion.setFromEuler( euler );

        camera.position.copy( motion.position );
        camera.position.y += 10.0;
    };
})();
```

Lets say I wanted to break this updateCamera function into its own file and import it. I'm a bit confused on how to since it's self executing. Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: I would reference this question to find your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32746615/namespacing-with-iife-in-es6.  The ES6 IIFE can be written in a few ways, but I prefer replacing it with a block scope wrapping { ... }.

Comment: where are you getting the variables `camera` and `motion`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning to the (global?) `updateCamera` variable, use a (default) export. You can drop the whole IIFE, as every module has its own scope; so `euler` will be inaccessible and static even in the module top level.

You also might want to explicitly declare the dependency on Three.js instead of relying on globals.

```
// updateCamera.js
import { Euler } from 'three';

var euler = new THREE.Euler( 0, 0, 0, 'YXZ' );

export default function updateCamera(camera, motion) {
    euler.x = motion.rotation.x;
    euler.y = motion.rotation.y;
    camera.quaternion.setFromEuler( euler );

    camera.position.copy( motion.position );
    camera.position.y += 10.0;
}
```

Then you can use it in other modules by doing

```
// main.js
import updateCamera from './updateCamera';

…
updateCamer(camera, motion);
```

Notice that `camera` and `motion` should be passed as arguments here. Again, don't depend on globals; if you don't want to pass them around everywhere you might also create a module that exports them and from which you could do

```
import {camera, motion} from './globals';
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

> Lets say I wanted to break this updateCamera function into its own file and import it. I'm a bit confused on how to since it's self executing. Can anyone give me a hand?

Well the only point of the IIFE in this case is to make `euler` "private". Because each file gives you its own context in Node, you can do this without the IIFE easily

```
// Camera.js

import { Euler } from 'three'

const euler = new Euler( 0, 0, 0, 'YXZ' )

export const updateCamera = (camera, motion) => {
  euler.x = motion.rotation.x
  euler.y = motion.rotation.y
  camera.quaternion.setFromEuler( euler )
  camera.position.copy( motion.position )
  camera.position.y += 10.0
}
```

Using it is like this

```
import { updateCamera } from './Camera'

// const camera = ..., motion = ...

updateCamera(camera, motion)
```