# What is the purpose of an IIFE in a module's index.js?

Tags: javascript, module, iife

I found this in the `index.js` of a module I used recently:

```
(function() {
  module.exports = require('./lib/somelib');
}).call(this);
```

These were the entire contents of the file. `somelib` had the definitions that were actually being exported. What would be the purpose of this and how is this different from simply having:

```
  module.exports = require('./lib/somelib');
```

I understand what an IIFE is for (typically for creating a closure with a reference to a "hidden" scoped variable. I'm having trouble seeing any benefit to this above pattern however.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Maybe IIFE is added automatically by some build process (i.e. it was not intentionally added)

Comment: [Coffeescript produces these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4542942/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi Looks like you're on the money (though it's hard to conclusively prove since the source I looked at didn't have any coffeescript AFAICT). The explanations on that page make sense. Feel free to make this an answer that I'll accept.